# Information about event in JS controller in AURA

Tags: aura, javascript-controller, aura-method

I would like to know where I can get relevant information about the methods that have the event of the aura controller, i.e. this my_function: function(cmp,***event***,hlp)... I know a lot of the others, but I've realized that I don't know much about the ***event*** and the methods it has. I hope for a prompt reply, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Aura is an event-driven architecture. In other words, your code will only run in response to events in the system, such as loading a component, a keyboard press or a mouse click, etc. In fact, this is why you need [$A.getCallback](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_jsapi_dollarA_getCallback.htm) when you use setInterval, setTimeout, and other native event handlers (e.g. HTMLImageElement.onload), because otherwise Aura isn't active, and you can't access most component functionality or fire events.

So, what is the `event`? Well, it's a `SecureEvent`. This is a custom event type that makes sure you don't accidentally leak restricted data, as defined by the Locker Service. In many ways, it acts like a normal event, except it is handled by Aura components instead of normal HTML components. You can see all of the available methods in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_jsapi_event.htm).